# ngrx - How to update another reducer inside an ActionReducerMap

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have the following ActionReducerMap

```js
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  people: fromCasting.peopleReducer,
  jobs: fromJob.jobReducer
};
```

When I create a new entity (Action: [Jobs Page] create job success) I push this new job inside my jobReducer but I also need to clean all entities inside the peopleReducer.

**How can I update one reducer when an action was dispatched to another reducer.**

Im I missing some redux concept?

Comment: Actions are global so you should be able to simply have a reducer listen to the action..?

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke a reducer from another reducer.
You could listen to the same action in the two reducers to update both states.